# snackbar positioning with md-dialog

Tags: html, css

Why the `md-dialog` is always on top? [DEMO](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-XG4gICAgICA8ZGl2PlxuICAgICAgICA8aG90LXRvYXN0PlxuICAgICAgICAgIDxkaXYgc3R5bGU9XCJwb3NpdGlvbjogYWJzb2x1dGU7IHRvcDogNTAlOyBsZWZ0OiA1MCVcIj5cbiAgICAgICAgICAgIHRvYXN0IHRlc3RcbiAgICAgICAgICA8L2Rpdj5cbiAgICAgICAgPC9ob3QtdG9hc3Q-XG4gICAgICA8L2Rpdj5cbiAgICA8L2Rpdj5cbiAgPC9kaXY-XG48L2hvdC10b2FzdC1jb250YWluZXI-XG5cbjxtZC1kaWFsb2cgb3Blbj5cbiAgPGRpdiBzbG90PVwiY29udGVudFwiPnRlc3Q8L2Rpdj5cbjwvbWQtZGlhbG9nPlxuXG4ifSx7Im5hbWUiOiJwYWNrYWdlLmpzb24iLCJjb250ZW50Ijoie1xuICBcImRlcGVuZGVuY2llc1wiOiB7XG4gICAgXCJsaXRcIjogXCJeMi4wLjBcIixcbiAgICBcIkBsaXQvcmVhY3RpdmUtZWxlbWVudFwiOiBcIl4xLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwibGl0LWVsZW1lbnRcIjogXCJeMy4wLjBcIixcbiAgICBcImxpdC1odG1sXCI6IFwiXjIuMC4wXCJcbiAgfVxufSIsImhpZGRlbiI6dHJ1ZX1d)

I tried z-index etc. and nothing works. Can you help me css masters?

```html
<hot-toast-container>
  <div style="position: fixed; z-index: 9999; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; pointer-events: none;">
    <div style="position: relative; height: 100%;">
      <div>
        <hot-toast>
          <div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%">
            toast test
          </div>
        </hot-toast>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</hot-toast-container>

<md-dialog open>
  <div slot="content">test</div>
</md-dialog>
```

Comment: It's on top because it has the `open` attribute. That is normal behaviour. You need to remove the `open` attribute. This is normally done by binding an `addEventListener` to an associated element and then calling `dialog.close();` within the callback. Please refer to the [docs](https://material-web.dev/components/dialog/#opening-and-closing).